# product listing load more time in category page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, optimization

In website 150k products,I have installed varnish cache but when initial load category page it takes 10 second to load time and display 36 products in category page and I do not want to change 36 to less pagination. I want to load category page in less time so how can I optimize query product collection?

I think it needs to optimze Collection from block  `Mage_Catalog_Product_List`. and method used is `_getProductCollection()`
so how to optimize in collection in `_getProductCollection()` method. Please guide me. I am using dedicated server. If anyone can give another solution it will appreciated.

Edit: I have already enabled flat catalog option.

Comment: do you have configurable product swatches on that listing page ?

Comment: No but product listing is configurable

Comment: I want to decrease first time load listing page time

Comment: so you dont have swatches on listing page ??

Comment: I know that swatches takes time to load page but no swatches in listing page

Comment: have you enable the catalog flat table?

Comment: I enabled but no change in category page

Comment: I enabled both category and product flat option from catalog configuration

Comment: Can optimize product collection ? If yes can you write it ? And how ?

Comment: remove unwanted attribute from flat table for that set no to listing page

Comment: I already set no 'used in product listing' from attribute setting for unwanted attributes .So in flat table only useable attributes there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly visit below URL for speed optimization for category pages. It is very helpful for you.

Category (configure product):

URL : https://astrio.net/blog/magento-performance-optimization-configurable-products-2/

Product page (configure product):

https://astrio.net/blog/magento-performance-optimization-configurable-products-2/